# Trigger Approval Process

Tags: community, opportunity, process-builder, approval-process

I created an Approval Process but I'm not aware how to trigger such approval process. What I would like to know is how to trigger the Approval Process when Opportunity stage = 'Proposal Submitted for Approval'. The stage field is a standard picklist field and when 'Proposal Submitted for Approval' in the stage picklist is selected then the Approval Process must be triggered automatically. As far as I'm concerned the Approval Process can be triggered automatically with the help of the Process Builder therefore I created a Process Builder but I'm not sure how to configure it to use my Approval Process and to be initialized when stage 'Proposal Submitted for Approval' is selected. 
Please advise how to trigger the Approval Process automatically when Opportunity stage is 'Proposal Submitted for Approval'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add the entry criteria for the records to be entered in the process builder.
- Check for the stage field matches 'Proposal Submitted for Approval'.
- Use Submit for approval (initiates an approval process) action.

For reference see the [Document](https://appirio.com/tech-blog/lightning-process-builder-how-to-initiate-the-approval-process)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flow to check if the field is set to 'Proposal Submitted for Approval'. Once the flow is created, you can create a quick action Submit for approval and place it on the page layout. Configure this quick action such that it invokes the flow. By having an entry criteria on your approval process, the concerned approval process would be invoked.